# Как получить массив уникальных символов и их количество из заданной строки?

Tags: javascript

Строку `var string ="Some string"` я преобразовал в массив отдельных символов путем

```
var result = string.split(''); // ["s", "o", "m", "e", "", "s", "t", "r", "i", "n", "g"]
```

Если применить `let uniqueNums = [ ...new Set (result)]` то получится массив только из уникальных символов, а мне нужна функция которая еще добавит в объект кол-во каждого символа в этой строке.

```
{symbol: "S", amount: 2}
{symbol: "o", amount: 1}
```

и т.д.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
let arr = ["h", "e", "l", "l", "o", " ", "w", "o", "r", "l", "d"];

let symbolsOccurenceMap = arr.reduce((acc, symbol) => {
    acc[symbol] = acc[symbol] ? acc[symbol] + 1 : 1; 
    return acc
}, {});

let resultMap = [];
for (let [symbol, count] of Object.entries(symbolsOccurenceMap)) {
    resultMap.push({ symbol, count });
}

// либо так
//resultMap = Object.entries(symbolsOccurenceMap).map(([symbol, count]) => {
//    return { symbol, count };
//});

console.log(resultMap);
```

Comment: спасибо! а не подскажите, как теперь запушить это в объект: {symbol: "S", amount: 2}
{symbol: "o", amount: 1}?

Comment: @АлександрСоколов чуть подправил ответ. можно циклом или мапой. Вместо count, можете сделать amount

Comment: Теперь оно! Благодарю!

Answer (score 1):

```js
//{symbol: "o", amount: 1}

var string = "Some string"
var total= [];
var result = string.split('');

result.forEach((s, i)=>{
total.push({sumbol:s, amount: i+1})
})

console.log(total);
```

Comment: Почти то что нужно, только "i" в данном случае получается порядковым номером, а не количеством:

Comment: { symbol: 'S', amount: 0 },
  { symbol: 'o', amount: 1 },
  { symbol: 'm', amount: 2 },
  { symbol: 'e', amount: 3 },
  { symbol: ' ', amount: 4 },
  { symbol: 's', amount: 5 },
  { symbol: 't', amount: 6 },
  { symbol: 'r', amount: 7 },
  { symbol: 'i', amount: 8 },
  { symbol: 'n', amount: 9 },
  { symbol: 'g', amount: 10 }

Comment: Изменил.........

Comment: К сожалению, это не то... я указал в описании:

Comment: {symbol: "S", amount: 2} // в новом массиве только уникальные символы
{symbol: "o", amount: 1} // их количество, напр. S 2 в массиве, поэтому amount 2...

Comment: Честно, не понял...  О каком количестве и символах  идет речь?

Comment: )) В строке "Some string" 2 s значит в результат будет { symbol: 'S', amount: 2 }

Comment: одна "O" значит  { symbol: 'о', amount: 1 } и т.д. по всем символам...